# How to recreate this effect, a mix of profile and front headshot?

Tags: portrait, image-manipulation, tutorial

I've seen several photos [like the example below](http://500px.com/photo/14373939) and I would like to create one. I think it overlaps a profile photo and a front headshot, with lots of local adjustments. Do you know of any (photoshop) tutorial explaining how to create it?

[image: Example photo]

Comment: Why would you want to? Yucc.

Comment: hahahah, I know the first time I felt that too :P it's just for the curiosity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a very clever and effective trick, but provided you have good quality source images it is not that difficult to achieve.

[image]

You need to overlay the profile and frontal images so they match up at the corner of the right eye and corner of the mouth (shown by the green circles). Then it's a case of blending between two layers along the red line.

Certain parts of the image might have to be nudged using the liquify tool (or similar) to line up better and there is evidence of this in the example you posted.

Answer (score 11):

You could have also just asked me directly, the guy in the picture. ;)

But yes, it's simply a profile and a frontal shot combined together, if the angles match it's actually not that hard to do.

Comment: Small world!! You're right I could have asked directly, but I had some past experiences with photographers that don't bother answering me, so this time I didn't even try it. Thanks mate ;)